# Tkinter allow window resizing from-to a certain amount

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, resize

I would like to have a window, which can be resized, but not "anyhow".
What I mean is there is a point, let's say 200x200 pixels after which the window is not resizable anymore, so it doesn't get smaller and an upper point like 1000x1000, after which it can'get bigger.

```
self.resizable(0, 0)
```

disables any size change and is not good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look towards `minsize(width, height)` and `maxsize(width, height)`

```
import tkinter as tk

def get_size():
    w = root.winfo_width()
    h = root.winfo_height()
    print(w, h)

root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(200, 200)
root.maxsize(1000, 1000)

btn = tk.Button(root, text = 'Get Current Window Size',\
                command = get_size)
btn.pack(expand = True)

root.mainloop()
```